# How to solve the "Undefined symbols in librouting.dylib" issue on Mac Os X?

Tags: installation, pgrouting, homebrew, apple

I'm trying to create a Homebrew formula to let anybody install pgrouting on his or her mac.

I've seen this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15314/how-to-fix-pgrouting-librouting-dd-so-undefined-symbol-error

I'm also following this documentation: http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/install_freebsd.html

I'm copy-pasting the whole message here:

```
==> Installing pgrouting
==> Downloading http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/source/pgrouting-1.05.tar.gz
File already downloaded in /Users/ca/Library/Caches/Homebrew
/usr/bin/tar xf /Users/ca/Library/Caches/Homebrew/pgrouting-1.05.tar.gz
==> Downloading patches
/usr/bin/curl -f#LA Homebrew 0.8 (Ruby 1.8.7-174; Mac OS X 10.6.8) https://gist.github.com/raw/1271301/d3c4db0d2ed68b2e9dd72289b73eecabbc2429b5/pgrouting-mac-os-x.patch -o 001-homebrew.diff
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
/usr/bin/patch -f -p1 -i 001-homebrew.diff
patching file core/src/edge_visitors.hpp
patching file core/src/shooting_star_boost_wrapper.cpp
patching file core/src/shooting_star_relax.hpp
==> cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX='/usr/local/Cellar/pgrouting/1.05' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None -Wno-dev -DPOSTGRESQL_INCLUDE_DIR='/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/include/server/' -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR='/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.47.0/include/boost/'
cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX='/usr/local/Cellar/pgrouting/1.05' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None -Wno-dev -DPOSTGRESQL_INCLUDE_DIR='/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/include/server/' -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR='/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.47.0/include/boost/' 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++-4.2
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++-4.2 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found PostgreSQL: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/include/server, /usr/local/lib/libpq.dylib
Boost headers were found here: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.47.0/include/boost/
Output directory for libraries is set to /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/lib
-- Found PGROUTING_CORE core: /tmp/homebrew-pgrouting-1.05-OhBx/pgrouting-1.05/core/src
Installation directory for libraries is set to /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/lib and for SQL files is set to /usr/share/postlbs
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/homebrew-pgrouting-1.05-OhBx/pgrouting-1.05
==> make
make 
Scanning dependencies of target routing
[ 16%] [ 33%] Building C object core/src/CMakeFiles/routing.dir/astar.o
Building C object core/src/CMakeFiles/routing.dir/dijkstra.o
[ 50%] Building C object core/src/CMakeFiles/routing.dir/shooting_star.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object core/src/CMakeFiles/routing.dir/boost_wrapper.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object core/src/CMakeFiles/routing.dir/astar_boost_wrapper.o
[100%] Building CXX object core/src/CMakeFiles/routing.dir/shooting_star_boost_wrapper.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/librouting.dylib
Undefined symbols:
  "_SPI_freetuptable", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_heap_formtuple", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_elog_start", referenced from:
      _finish in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _finish in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _finish in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_pfree", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_Float8GetDatum", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_init_MultiFuncCall", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_BlessTupleDesc", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_SPI_prepare", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_SPI_fnumber", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_MemoryContextAlloc", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_errmsg", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_repalloc", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_end_MultiFuncCall", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_SPI_getvalue", referenced from:
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_per_MultiFuncCall", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_errstart", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_SPI_cursor_fetch", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_SPI_gettypeid", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_SPI_cursor_open", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_SPI_getbinval", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_errfinish", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_SPI_finish", referenced from:
      _finish in dijkstra.o
      _finish in astar.o
      _finish in shooting_star.o
  "_RelationNameGetTupleDesc", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_CurrentMemoryContext", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_SPI_connect", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_elog_finish", referenced from:
      _finish in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _finish in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _finish in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_errcode", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_DatumGetFloat8", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_SPI_tuptable", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_pg_detoast_datum", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
  "_SPI_processed", referenced from:
      _shortest_path in dijkstra.o
      _shortest_path_astar in astar.o
      _shortest_path_shooting_star in shooting_star.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/librouting.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [core/src/CMakeFiles/routing.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
==> Exit Status: 2
http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/pgrouting.rb#L18
==> Environment
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8
HEAD: f2acf83b0e0f344b89411fb884af5dfaacf890eb
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
Hardware: dual-core 64-bit penryn
OS X: 10.6.8
Kernel Architecture: i386
Ruby: 1.8.7-174
/usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Xcode: 3.2.6
GCC-4.0: build 5494 
GCC-4.2: build 5666 
LLVM: build 2335 
MacPorts or Fink? false
X11 installed? true
==> Build Flags
CC: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
CXX: /usr/bin/g++-4.2
LD: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
CFLAGS: -O3 -march=core2 -msse4.1 -w -pipe
CXXFLAGS: -O3 -march=core2 -msse4.1 -w -pipe
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/include
LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/lib
MAKEFLAGS: -j2
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/lib/pkgconfig

Error: Failed executing: make 
If `brew doctor' does not help diagnose the issue, please report the bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/checklist-before-filing-a-new-issue
```

Thanks for your help!

---

For those interested, you can checkout my Homebrew fork here: https://github.com/charlax/homebrew

I have added two formulas: pgrouting and gaul. Hope that helps!

If everything's right, you should be able to install pgrouting like this (you need to add my two formulas before):

```
$ brew install pgrouting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer there: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/commit/8574864fcce8f37acabe40b985b36c6c3e8c7bdd