# Issues with installing pgrouting in mac

Tags: pgrouting, mac

I installed both postgresql and postgis using brew in mac. How can I now install pgrouting. I couldn't install it using brew. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you build on MacOSX, pgrouting git-master version is necessary.
See another question ([How to solve the “Undefined symbols in librouting.dylib” issue on Mac Os X?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15464/how-to-solve-the-undefined-symbols-in-librouting-dylib-issue-on-mac-os-x%20test)).

```
$ cd ~/
$ mkdir -p Build/cpp/pgrouting-git
$ cd Build/cpp/pgrouting-git
$ git clone git://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting.git .
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -DPOSTGRESQL_INCLUDE_DIR='/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.3/include/server' -DBoost_DIR='/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0' ..
$ vi ../core/src/edge_visitors.hpp
-- edit as follows.
-- #include <boost/graph/detail/is_same.hpp>
--  => #include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: I tried to install it as you said. But it agains says Could not find Boost FATAL ERROR Please check your Boost installation. I have already installed boost using homebrew. Is there anything else that I should do?

Comment: I have got the following errorcmake -DPOSTGRESQL_INCLUDE_DIR='/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2/include/server/' -DBOOST_DIR='/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost/'
-- Could NOT find Boost
FATALERROR Please check your Boost installation 
Output directory for libraries is set to /usr/lib/postgresql

Comment: I had installed boost from cgal dependencies with homebrew. In my environment, "brew info boost" result is as follows  boost 1.49.0  http://www.boost.org  /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0 (9053 files, 239M) *  https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/boostrb

Comment: I have the same in mine as well

Comment: -DBoost_DIR word must be case sensitive, and suffix should be "~/1.49.0" (last "/include/boost" word is not necessary).

Comment: I tried that as well but it's not working

Comment: Sorry, in my environment, "ls -al /usr/local/include/boost" result is "~ -> .. /Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/boost". Please modify "DBoost_DIR" to "DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR", and "~/1.49.0" to "~/1.49.0/include".

Comment: But now when I do make It shows library not found for -lgmp

Comment: ok I installed gmp using brew install gmp and it solved the problem. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 3):

You can download Mac OS X installers from this website: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres

I don't know this is compatible with what you installed using brew, but the PostgreSQL/PostGIS binaries you can get from that website should work well, too.

Comment: I don't think it is compatible with the one I installed using brew

Comment: I tried to install it from the source using cmake. But it said it couldn't find boost. So I installed it using brew (brew install boost) but still it says it cannot find boost.

Comment: kyngchaos's installer unfortunately does not allow itself to work with postgresql 9.2